# How to fix redundancy of ArrayList after construction in android

Tags: java, android

I was making a food ordering application where I got stuck. I am calling the constructor of my class. Then, after assignment, `this.listData` my `ArrayList` is being reported redundant.

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartViewHolder> {

    private List<Order> listData = new ArrayList<>();

    private Context context;

    public CartAdapter(List<Order> listData, Context context) {
        this.listData = listData;
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you calling "redundant"? This is reference copy and your list will only be present once in memory

Comment: What do you meant through `"redundant"`? How do you create an object of your `CartAdapter` class? Please also responde with @.

Comment: If that is your only constructor, you don't need to initialize `listData` at the declaration. And `listData` and `context` should probably also be final.

Comment: @ Alex Mamo ,Sir by redundant I mean to say that after writing this.listData=listData    my new ArrayList<>()  got faded in Android Studio.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a Linked List here?

Comment: @PRANAVSINHA you are using Android Studio, so the message comes from the IDE and it is related to the initialisation. Please check my answer and accept it if it helped you solving your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your IDE gives you the message that the following initialisation is redundant, not the  field itself.

`private List<Order> listData = new ArrayList<>();`

The idea is that you have only one constructor, and this constructor expects all the time a `List<Order>`. This means that each time you make an instance of the class, you will be able to use the only constructor you provided, in which the field `listData` will have the value of the first parameter of the only constructor, so there is no need to initialize the field like that. This is why you get the "redundant initialisation" warning.

If you want to have a way of initialising the `listData` as an empty `ArrayList`, then you can provide an constructor where you don't handle the `listData` field. Otherwise, declaring `private List<Order> listData;` will do "the trick".

Comment: ,Sir can you please elaborate this concept.

Comment: @PRANAVSINHA You have only one constructor. The constructor has 2 parameters. The first one is `List<Order> listData`, which gets attributed to the class field `listData`, here: `this.listData = listData;`. This means that you do not need to provide an initialisation for the field.

Comment: @PRANAVSINHA please accept my answer now that I have elaborated.